# The .pop() method is not working in my if statement

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to access an array that looks like this: `["12","11","5:","10","1:","12"]`. I am iterating through each component of the array and testing to see if the string in the array has its [1] index filled with an ":", and if so, to remove it using the method .pop(). But when I try and run it, the console returns `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: firstTwo[i].pop() is not a function`. I am wondering if it is because I am trying to pop off a string datatype? I tried slice and splice but both returned similar results.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  console.log(dayInfo[i]); //would print as ex. 12:53:04
  firstNum[i] = dayInfo[i][0]; //takes the 1
  secondNum[i] = dayInfo[i][1]; //takes the 2
  firstTwo[i] = firstNum[i] + "" + secondNum[i]; //Combines the 2 numbers into the array you saw above
  if (firstTwo[i][1] === ':') {
    firstTwo[i].pop();
  }
}
```

Comment: Please write a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: `firstTwo[i]` is a string, not an array

Comment: It looks like you want to remove an element from an array at its index. pop() removes the _last_ element of the array, but you're calling it on the string, not the array. `firstTwo.pop()` would call it on the array. but you should never change an array you're looping over. And you probably want to remove by index, not remove the last element

Comment: `["12","11","5:","10","1:","12"].map(it => it.replace(/[:]/, ''))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here

```
firstTwo[i]=firstNum[i]+""+secondNum[i]; //Combines the 2 numbers into the array you saw above
```

What you typed there does **NOT** define an array called `firstTwo`;

If you want to define an array containing those first two values, use the correct syntax like this

```
firstTwo[i]=[firstNum[i],secondNum[i]];
```

Please read [How to create an array in Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) for further information

Comment: thank you, this made me realize my problem and made it easier to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

Pop is an array method that will always remove the last element from the array, `firstTwo[i]` is not an array, is an element, the method you need is called. [Splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Use it like this:

```
firstTwo.splice(i, 1)
```

That will remove that element, but it will shift the array indexes, so be careful.

A better way, could also be with the filter function.

```
firstTwo.filter(e => !e.startsWith(':'))
```